# Having troubles sorting SQL query results with Order by and Group By functions with Aggregated fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am encountering some issues with the results of the following query.

My intention is to display the results of the total payments received by the hosts, sorted in descending order based on the aggregated column (aliased as 'Total Amount Received ($)'

```
Select   H.host_name AS 'Host Name', 
         H.location AS 'District', 
         AVG(F.host_feedback_rating) AS 'Average Rating',
         SUM(P.payment_amount) AS 'Total Amount Received ($)'

FROM booking B, host H, payments P, feedback F 
WHERE H.host_id = P.host_id
AND F.booking_code = B.booking_code
AND F.host_id = H.host_id
AND P.payment_date  between '2018/01/01' and '2018/12/31'

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 'Total Amount Received ($)' DESC;
```

Current Results:

```
Host Name   District    Average Rating  Total Amount Received ($)
John         Detroit              5                275
Leeroy       Chicago              5                50
Rinoa        Texas                5                225
Sally        California           4                45
```

I've tried adjusting the GROUP BY clauses, but somehow the Total Amount Received ($) does not get sorted correctly... Could you please guide me on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about `order by SUM(P.payment_amount) desc` ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Total Amount Received ($)'` is surrounded by single quotes (`'`), and is thus a constant string literal. While sorting according to it isn't technically wrong (as you could see - you got no error), it's meaningless, as all the rows would have the same value of the constant.

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to sort according to the column's index instead of its alias:

```
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks for the detailed explanation on the string literal classification, it really helped to provide some context behind the issue!

Answer (score 0):

try with backtick like

```
...ORDER BY `Total Amount Received ($)` DESC
```

OR

```
...Order By 4 DESC
```

or

```
...SUM(P.payment_amount) DESC
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your time and the suggestion! I went ahead with Order By 4 DESC, working as expected :)